# Weird behavior with strpos

Tags: php, web, autocomplete, xmlhttprequest, strpos

I'm programming an autocomplete system and i'm using strpos to look fo occurences of a given input in a  txt file.

```
<?php
    $request=$_POST['req'];//the input received
    $file=fopen('file1.txt','r');
    $string='';
    while(($current=fgets($file))!==false){
         if (strpos($current,$request,0)!==false) {
             $string=$string.$current.'<br/>';
         }
    };
    fclose($file);
    echo $string;
?>
```

i don't know why , but it doesn't work properly when the given input is the start of string in the file.
For example:Let's say that the file contains Metal Gear Solid on a line.
If i type '  tal ' --> match found but
If i type ' meta ' --> match not found.

Comment: might be a letter case issue. try stripos which is for case insensitivity.

Comment: Wow thanks ! it works now.

Comment: plus, how often I see people creeping up behind me and posting an answer based on my comments. either delete the question or ask me to post it as an answer. I don't have a kind regard for vampires ;-) edit: never mind, @Dagon found a duplicate for it.

Comment: hang on i have the answer for you @Fred-ii- ....

Comment: Thanks @Dagon good move. works for moi.

Comment: i recommend a db, opening a file, looping a file, on every key press (depending on your js) is a little harsh